# How do I export from a namespace, accessing the default?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a question about ES6 import module.

I tried to add OrbitControls in my Three.js Code.
Since OrbitControls is a separate module, I needed to import them individually in my code as below. and it's working fine.

```
import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols'
```

**However,**

What I first expected was

```
import {OrbitControls} from 'three-orbitcontrols'
```

The reason is,

As far as I understood, if the module export something as export default,

I can access them by putting curly bracketing in my 'import' code.
But,it didn't workout so I assumed that 'three-orbitcontrols' doesn't export "OrbitControls" as a default.

**Then I tried like this**

```
import * as Orbit from 'three-orbitcontrols'

new Orbit.OrbitControls(a,b)
```

However,it didn't work out either.

What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly brackets are used when importing to import a *named export* from the other file. For example, the following link up:

```
export const foo = 'something';
```

```
import { foo } from './somefile.js';
```

Default exports do not use curly brackets:

```
export default 'somethingelse';
```

```
import theSomethingElse from './someOtherFile.js';
```

It sounds like `OrbitControls` uses default exports, so you should avoid curly brackets when importing.

Doing

```
import * as Orbit from 'three-orbitcontrols'
```

imports *everything* the module exports as a namespace, which is essentially an object. To access the default export from a namespace, access the `default` property on it:

```
import * as Orbit from 'three-orbitcontrols'

new Orbit.default(a,b)
```

(or just use your original version: `import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols'`)